# Screen not appearing in python turtle

Tags: python-turtle

This is my code

```
import turtle
scr = turtle.Screen()
```

When I run it the screen appears and then disappears, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Can you include them in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `scr.mainloop()` at the end of your code.